# PostgreSQL GIN index slower than GIST for pg_trgm?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, pattern-matching, postgresql-performance

Despite what all the documentation says, I'm finding GIN indexes to be significantly slower than GIST indexes for pg_trgm related searches. This is on a table of 25 million rows with a relatively short text field (average length of 21 characters). Most of the rows of text are addresses of the form "123 Main st, City".

GIST index takes about 4 seconds with a search like

```
select suggestion from search_suggestions where suggestion % 'seattle';
```

But GIN takes 90 seconds and the following result when running with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on search_suggestions  (cost=330.09..73514.15 rows=25043 width=22) (actual time=671.606..86318.553 rows=40482 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: ((suggestion)::text % 'seattle'::text)
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 23214341
  Heap Blocks: exact=7625 lossy=223807
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tri_suggestions_idx  (cost=0.00..323.83 rows=25043 width=0) (actual time=669.841..669.841 rows=1358175 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((suggestion)::text % 'seattle'::text)
Planning time: 1.420 ms
Execution time: 86327.246 ms
```

Note that over a million rows are being selected by the index, even though only 40k rows actually match. Any ideas why this is performing so poorly? This is on PostgreSQL 9.4.

Comment: Some information for a performance question is missing. Table definition, total size of table and index. [See instructions here.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some issues stand out:

First, consider upgrading to a **current version of Postgres**. At the time of writing that's pg 9.6 or pg 10 (currently beta). Since Pg 9.4 there have been multiple improvements for GIN indexes, the additional module pg_trgm and big data in general.

Next, you need much more **RAM**, in particular a higher **`work_mem`** setting. I can tell from this line in the `EXPLAIN` output:

```
Heap Blocks: exact=7625 lossy=223807
```

*"lossy"* in the details for a *Bitmap Heap Scan* (with your particular numbers) indicates a dramatic shortage of `work_mem`. Postgres only collects block addresses in the bitmap index scan instead of row pointers because that's expected to be faster with your low `work_mem` setting (can't hold exact addresses in RAM). Many more non-qualifying rows have to be filtered in the following *Bitmap Heap Scan* this way. This related answer has details:

- [“Recheck Cond:” line in query plans with a bitmap index scan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/106267/3684)

But don't set `work_mem` *too* high without considering the whole situation:

- [Optimize simple query using ORDER BY date and text](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48633/3684)

There may other problems, like index or table bloat or more configuration bottlenecks. But if you fix just these two items, the query should be *much* faster already.

Also, do you really need to retrieve all 40k rows in the example? You probably want to add a small **`LIMIT`** to the query and make it a "nearest-neighbor" search - in which case a GiST index is the better choice after all, because *that* is supposed to be faster with a GiST index. Example:

- [Best index for similarity function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/103823/3684)

Comment: Thanks so much! The machine has plenty of memory, so I'll try increasing the work_mem setting. The final query would use a limit, I left it off of the example for simplicity - adding it didn't change the query plan (besides the obvious addition of a limit).