# Optimizing a postgres similarity query (pg_trgm + gin index)

Tags: postgresql, pg-trgm

I have defined the following index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX
    users_search_idx
ON
    auth_user
USING
    gin(
        username gin_trgm_ops,
        first_name gin_trgm_ops,
        last_name gin_trgm_ops
    );
```

I am performing the following query:

```sql
PREPARE user_search (TEXT, INT) AS
    SELECT
        username,
        email,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        ( -- would probably do per-field weightings here
            s_username + s_first_name + s_last_name
        ) rank
    FROM
        auth_user,
        similarity(username, $1) s_username,
        similarity(first_name, $1) s_first_name,
        similarity(last_name, $1) s_last_name
    WHERE
        username % $1 OR
        first_name % $1 OR
        last_name % $1
    ORDER BY
        rank DESC
    LIMIT $2;
```

The `auth_user` table has 6.2 million rows.

The speed of the query seems to depend very heavily on the number of results potentially returned by the `similarity` query.

Increasing the similarity threshold via `set_limit` helps, but reduces usefulness of results by eliminating partial matches.

Some searches return in 200ms, others take ~ 10 seconds.

We have an existing implementation of this feature using Elasticsearch that returns in < 200ms for any query, while doing more complicated (better) ranking.

I would like to know if there is any way we could improve this to get more consistent performance?

It's my understanding that GIN index (inverted index) is the same basic approach used by Elasticsearch so I would have thought there is some optimization possible.

An `EXPLAIN ANALYZE EXECUTE user_search('mel', 20)` shows:

```
Limit  (cost=54099.81..54099.86 rows=20 width=52) (actual time=10302.092..10302.104 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=54099.81..54146.66 rows=18739 width=52) (actual time=10302.091..10302.095 rows=20 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (((s_username.s_username + s_first_name.s_first_name) + s_last_name.s_last_name)) DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=382.74..53601.17 rows=18739 width=52) (actual time=118.164..10293.765 rows=8380 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=382.74..53132.69 rows=18739 width=56) (actual time=118.150..10262.804 rows=8380 loops=1)
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=382.74..52757.91 rows=18739 width=52) (actual time=118.142..10233.990 rows=8380 loops=1)
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on auth_user  (cost=382.74..52383.13 rows=18739 width=48) (actual time=118.128..10186.816 rows=8380loops=1)"
                                Recheck Cond: (((username)::text % 'mel'::text) OR ((first_name)::text % 'mel'::text) OR ((last_name)::text %'mel'::text))"
                                Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 2434523
                                Heap Blocks: exact=49337 lossy=53104
                                ->  BitmapOr  (cost=382.74..382.74 rows=18757 width=0) (actual time=107.436..107.436 rows=0 loops=1)
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on users_search_idx  (cost=0.00..122.89 rows=6252 width=0) (actual time=40.200..40.200rows=88908 loops=1)"
                                            Index Cond: ((username)::text % 'mel'::text)
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on users_search_idx  (cost=0.00..122.89 rows=6252 width=0) (actual time=43.847..43.847rows=102028 loops=1)"
                                            Index Cond: ((first_name)::text % 'mel'::text)
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on users_search_idx  (cost=0.00..122.89 rows=6252 width=0) (actual time=23.387..23.387rows=58740 loops=1)"
                                            Index Cond: ((last_name)::text % 'mel'::text)
                          ->  Function Scan on similarity s_username  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=8380)
                    ->  Function Scan on similarity s_first_name  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=8380)
              ->  Function Scan on similarity s_last_name  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=8380)
Execution time: 10302.559 ms
```

Server is Postgres 9.6.1 running on Amazon RDS

### update

1.

Shortly after posting the question I found this info: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/464F3C5D.2000700@enterprisedb.com

So I tried

```
-> SHOW work_mem;
4MB
-> SET work_mem='12MB';
-> EXECUTE user_search('mel', 20);
(results returned in ~1.5s)
```

This made a big improvement (previously > 10s)!

*1.5s is still way slower than ES for similar query so I would still like to hear any suggestions for optimising the query.*

2.

In response to comments, and after seeing this question ([Postgresql GIN index slower than GIST for pg_trgm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008382/postgresql-gin-index-slower-than-gist-for-pg-trgm)), I tried exactly the same set up with a GIST index in place of the GIN one.

Trying the same search above, it returned in ~3.5s, using default `work_mem='4MB'`.  Increasing `work_mem` made no difference.

From this I conclude that GIST index is more memory efficient (did not hit pathological case like GIN did) but is slower than GIN when GIN is working properly. This is inline with what's described in the docs recommending GIN index.

3.

I still don't understand why so much time is spent in:

```
 ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on auth_user  (cost=382.74..52383.13 rows=18739 width=48) (actual time=118.128..10186.816 rows=8380loops=1)"
     Recheck Cond: (((username)::text % 'mel'::text) OR ((first_name)::text % 'mel'::text) OR ((last_name)::text %'mel'::text))"
     Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 2434523
     Heap Blocks: exact=49337 lossy=53104
```

I don't understand why this step is needed or what it's doing.

There are the three `Bitmap Index Scan` beneath it for each of the `username % $1` clauses... these results then get combined with a `BitmapOr` step. These parts are all quite fast.

But even in the case where we don't run out of work mem, we still spend nearly a whole second in `Bitmap Heap Scan`.

Comment: So... the huge majority of the time is spent in costly `Bitmap Heap Scan on auth_user Recheck Cond`.  For some reason this has to remove 2.4 million rows, although the inner Index Scans return < 300k rows total.  I don't understand what is happening here

Comment: Why are you doing the similarity calls in the FROM clause? You don't appear to be doing anything with them apart from in the SELECT clause.
Note that the total time used there is the "actual time" * "loops" although I wouldn't put too much faith in the figure for "actual time" - it's too small to be a reliable figure.

Comment: similarity in the FROM is something I got from an example query somewhere... it makes it more readable.  I tried moving into the SELECT portion but no difference in performance.  The actual time on this query is 10s... for some searches I am getting the worst case exactly as reported in the EXPLAIN above

Comment: I have actually just found something that makes a big difference ... `SET work_mem='8MB'` (from 4MB) cuts the worst case down to ~1.3s. So I guess the main problem is as described here https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/464F3C5D.2000700@enterprisedb.com

Comment: 1.3s is not really awesome but its much better than 10s

Comment: Have you tried the `gist` index method (instead of `gin`)? -- Is a [*word-similarity*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) over the `CONCAT(username, ' ', first_name, ' ', last_name)` expression acceptable for you? (It works a little bit different from what you use, but it should be searched/ordered faster than your current index).

Comment: @pozs I did briefly experiment with word similarity operators but they seemed even slower.  I have created a GIST index with identical spec but so far the query planner does not choose it. I may try dropping the GIN index to compare

Comment: @Anentropic yes, having both might confuse the planner -- a single, expression-based index would eliminate the need for `BitmapOr` (under `Bitmap Heap Scan`).

Comment: the `Bitmap Heap Scan` is by far the slowest part of the query though

Comment: same queries using identical GIST index: worst case time ~3.7s (work_mem=4MB) ...no improvement with work_mem=8MB

Comment: Great question, I would very much like to upvote it but my policy prohibits me from upvoting open but already answered questions.

Comment: @raratiru I was hoping for other answers. Are you saying you think I should have accepted the first one received?

Comment: No not at all, apologies for not reading the comments in the answer! I am currently digging into this issue of trying to optimize such a query.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I expect ***much*** faster results with this approach:

#### 1.

Create a GiST index with 1 column holding concatenated values:

```
CREATE INDEX users_search_idx ON auth_user
USING gist((username || ' ' || first_name || ' ' || last_name) gist_trgm_ops);
```

This assumes all 3 columns to be defined `NOT NULL` (you did not specify). Else you need to do more.
Why not simplify with `concat_ws()`?

- [Combine two columns and add into one new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310986/combine-two-columns-and-add-into-one-new-column/12320369#12320369)
- [Faster query with pattern-matching on multiple text fields](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/117425/3684)
- [Combine two columns and add into one new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310986/combine-two-columns-and-add-into-one-new-column/12320369#12320369)

#### 2.

Use a proper [nearest-neighbor](/questions/tagged/nearest-neighbor) query, matching above index:

```
SELECT username, email, first_name, last_name
     , similarity(username  , $1) AS s_username
     , similarity(first_name, $1) AS s_first_name
     , similarity(last_name , $1) AS s_last_name
     , row_number() OVER () AS rank  -- greatest similarity first
FROM   auth_user
WHERE     (username || ' ' || first_name || ' ' || last_name) %   $1  -- !!
ORDER  BY (username || ' ' || first_name || ' ' || last_name) <-> $1  -- !!
LIMIT  $2;
```

Expressions in `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` must match index expression!

In particular `ORDER BY rank` (like you had it) will always perform poorly for a small `LIMIT` picking from a much larger pool of qualifying rows, because it cannot use an index directly: The sophisticated expression behind `rank` has to be calculated for *every* qualifying row, then all have to be sorted before the small selection of best matches can be returned. This is ***much, much more expensive*** than a true nearest-neighbor query that can pick the best results from the index directly without even looking at the rest.

`row_number()` with empty window definition just reflects the ordering produced by the `ORDER BY` of the same `SELECT`.

Related answers:

- [Best index for similarity function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/103823/3684)
- [Search in 300 million addresses with pg_trgm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773387/search-in-300-million-addresses-with-pg-trgm/44838192#44838192)

---

As for your item `3.`, I added an answer to the question you referenced, that should explain it:

- [PostgreSQL GIN index slower than GIST for pg_trgm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008382/postgresql-gin-index-slower-than-gist-for-pg-trgm/44853236#44853236)

Comment: if I understood correctly, the most important change is `ORDER  BY (username || ' ' || first_name || ' ' || last_name) <-> $1`.  I had been hoping to later tweak my `rank` value to boost username matches, eg `((s_username * 2) + s_first_name + s_last_name) rank` but it seems like this wouldn't be possible in the optimised version

Comment: @Anentropic: The point of the optimization is that the query can pick the best matches from the index directly, which is much, much faster than retrieving all candidates, computing a rank for each, sorting all of them by this rank and then discarding all but the first ones - while `LIMIT` is substantially smaller than the total number of qualifying rows.