How to make a query with ILIKE filters on multiple columns in two tables?
I have a non-optimized query with ILIKE filters on 6 columns in the first table, and on one more column in the second table.
There are more than 13 million records in the table. This request is processed in 80 seconds. Which is a very long time. Since ILIKE is used, indexing does not work. How can I optimize my query? Maybe I need to create a FULL TEXT INDEX for all fields?

DDL and test data https://dbfiddle.uk/JCZVw0v6

Version PostgreSQL - 10.21

Query


from "sms" 
left join "user_apps" on "user_apps"."id" = "sms"."user_app_id" 
where "user_apps"."unique_id" ilike '%search_text%'
or "sms.sender" ilike '%search_text%'
or "sms.message" ilike '%search_text%'
or "sms.msisdn_receiver" ilike '%search_text%'
or "sms"."country_code" ilike '%search_text%'
or CAST(sms.id as VARCHAR(255)) ilike '%search_text%'
or "sms.sim" ilike '%search_text%' 
or "sms"."status" ilike '%search_text%'
and "sms.type" = 'sms' 
order by "smsId" desc 
limit 51 offset 0


Cardinalities - 13 million records

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS)


EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS) select *, "user_apps"."id" as "uaId", "sms"."id" as "smsId"
from "sms"
    left join "user_apps" on "user_apps"."id" = "sms"."user_app_id"
where "user_apps"."unique_id" ilike '%13568034%'
    or "sms.sender" ilike '%13568034%'
    or "sms.message" ilike '%13568034%'
    or "sms.msisdn_receiver" ilike '%13568034%'
    or "sms"."country_code" ilike '%13568034%'
    or CAST(sms.id as VARCHAR(255)) ilike '%13568034%'
    or "sms.sim" ilike '%13568034%'
    or "sms"."status" ilike '%13568034%'
    and "sms.type" = 'sms'
    order by "smsId" desc
    limit 51 offset 0

Limit  (cost=1000.77..17388.49 rows=51 width=1349) (actual time=35122.310..35359.126 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=24704683 read=647586
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.77..1754487.38 rows=5457 width=1349) (actual time=35122.305..35359.116 rows=1 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 4
        Workers Launched: 4
        Buffers: shared hit=24704683 read=647586
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.71..1752837.34 rows=1364 width=1341) (actual time=28087.631..28087.696 rows=0 loops=5)
              Filter: (((user_apps.unique_id)::text ~~* '%13568034%'::text) OR ((sms.sender)::text ~~* '%13568034%'::text) OR ((sms.message)::text ~~* '%13568034%'::text) OR ((sms.msisdn_receiver)::text ~~* '%13568034%'::text) OR ((sms.country_code)::text ~~* '%13568034%'::text) OR (((sms.id)::character varying(255))::text ~~* '%13568034%'::text) OR ((sms.sim)::text ~~* '%13568034%'::text) OR (((sms.status)::text ~~* '%13568034%'::text) AND ((sms.type)::text = 'sms'::text)))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 2695161
              Buffers: shared hit=24704683 read=647586
              ->  Parallel Index Scan Backward using sms_pkey on sms  (cost=0.43..618823.77 rows=3410216 width=229) (actual time=0.092..7920.969 rows=2695161 loops=5)
                    Buffers: shared hit=7796122 read=647570
              ->  Index Scan using user_apps_pkey on user_apps  (cost=0.28..0.29 rows=1 width=1112) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=13475805)
                    Index Cond: (id = sms.user_app_id)
                    Buffers: shared hit=16908561 read=16
Planning time: 9.966 ms
Execution time: 35359.380 ms


A trigram index on all these columns should help: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html.

@Dogbert  thank you, Is there a separate index for each column or a common index?

Related case for a trigram index on multiple columns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44856792/939860 Basics for ILIKE patterns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452528/939860 CAST(message.id as VARCHAR(255)) is suspicious. I smell issues with your relational model. Also, why all digits in your search pattern? Provide more information if you want a good answer - as instructed here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

@ErwinBrandstetter thank you. I added new data to the question.
CAST(message.id as VARCHAR(255))
This column is of type integer and is primary key.
I need the ability to search by ID, so I turn it into an char type. For example id=13194467, when I search for 44, I should get back this id 13194467

@AlexBlack From your execution plan can be seen that some buffers are read (form disk instead of hit from memory). Issue a SELECT setting, unit FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'shared_buffers'; to see the size of your database buffers (that number must be mutiplied by unit, 80k usually, to see actual size in kbs).
It's recommended 25% of server's RAM for buffers, and usually is left on it's defult value, that is 16384 * 8kb = 128Mb. When your storage is not in SSD's there is an improvement in performance.

@PepeNO setting -262144;unit - 8kB

That's 2Gb, if possible increment it to 3Gb (or 4Gb depending on the outputs of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS)), you can change this parameter in postgresql.conf file and a database restart is required. Also or CAST(sms.id as VARCHAR(255)) ilike '%13568034%' if both are just numbers a comparison/search of integers is more efficient that one of text.

@PepeNO CAST(message.id as VARCHAR(255)) This column is of type integer and is primary key. I need the ability to search by ID, so I turn it into an char type. For example id=13194467, when I search for 44, I should get back this id 13194467. Is there another way to look for 44 (or any other number) ?

@AlexBlack: You provided some useful info. More is missing. Tell us about possible search patterns. So far it seems like all digits. But I doubt that. All meta information matters when optimizing queries. Crucially, provide exact table definitions for both involved tables (CREATE TABLE statement showing all relevant columns with data types and constraints). And table-qualify all columns in the query to make it unambiguous

As commented by @ErwinBrandstetter we need ddl of tables and indexes and some dummy data and expected result to solve this.

To optimize a query take into account execution order  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/order-of-execution-of-sql-queries/ and put the most restrictive condition in the upper level, maybe as a CTE (to reduce the set cardinality, aside of proper indexing).

@PepeNO I've added a link to dbfiddle.uk in the question

Postgres version
The first problem is your outdated Postgres version. Postgres 10 has reached end-of-life late 2022 And you are not even on the latest point-release, which is 10.23. Upgrade to a current version. It will help your case in any case. (But it's not the solution.)
Fix your query first
Seems like your query is in conflict with operator precedence. Fix by adding parentheses.
This is awkward:
or CAST(sms.id as VARCHAR(255)) ilike '%search_text%'

varchar(255) is a misunderstanding. See:

Refactor foreign key to fields

One of these would make more sense:
or sms.id::text LIKE '%search_text%'
or sms.id::text ~ 'search_text'

(Below optimization gets rid of it completely.)
Preliminary:
SELECT *, u.id AS "uaId", s.id AS "smsId"
FROM   sms s
LEFT   JOIN user_apps u ON u.id = s.user_app_id
WHERE  s.type = 'sms'
AND   (u.unique_id       ILIKE '%13568034%'
    OR s.sender          ILIKE '%13568034%'
    OR s.message         ILIKE '%13568034%'
    OR s.msisdn_receiver ILIKE '%13568034%'
    OR s.country_code    ILIKE '%13568034%'
    OR s.id::text         LIKE '%13568034%'  -- !
    OR s.sim             ILIKE '%13568034%'
    OR s.status          ILIKE '%13568034%')  -- parentheses !!!
ORDER  BY s.id DESC
LIMIT  51
OFFSET 0;

Rewrite for performance
Core topics (after fixing broken logic above):

Trigram index on concatenated column of table sms

Trigram index on user_apps.unique_id

Break up query to get rid of "ugly OR"

Replace SELECT * with only needed columns in the SELECT list


Auxiliary function
Your columns can be null, so concatenation with basic || gets tedious quickly. See:

Combine two columns and add into one new column

We want concat_ws() but IMMUTABLE for the index, so create a custom one. See:

Create an immutable clone of concat_ws
PostgreSQL full text search on many columns

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION immutable_concat_ws(text, VARIADIC text[])
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE internal IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
'text_concat_ws';

Requires superuser access. If you don't have that, fall back to next best option:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION immutable_concat_ws(text, VARIADIC text[])
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT concat_ws($1, $2);
$func$;

Trigram indexes
Use the above function in a trigram index to make this fast. See:

PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations

CREATE INDEX sms_multi_trgm_gin_index ON sms USING gin (immutable_concat_ws('|', sender, message, msisdn_receiver, country_code, id::text, sim, status) gin_trgm_ops);

I use '|' as separator. Use any character that's never used in search patterns, to avoid false positives!
And a plain index on user_apps:
CREATE INDEX user_apps_unique_id_trgm_gin_index ON user_apps USING gin (unique_id gin_trgm_ops);

Query
Reform your query to make use of above indexes
Also break up the ugly OR that would still kill performance. See:

Why is an OR statement slower than UNION?

SELECT * is typically a pointless waste for the many columns in your tables. Reduce to columns you need returned. I made up a list.
SELECT u.unique_id, s.sender, s.message, s.msisdn_receiver, s.country_code, s.id, s.sim, s.status
     , u.id AS "uaId", s.id AS "smsId"
FROM   sms s
LEFT   JOIN user_apps u ON u.id = s.user_app_id
WHERE  s.type = 'sms'
AND    immutable_concat_ws('|', s.sender, s.message, s.msisdn_receiver, s.country_code, s.id::text, s.sim, s.status) ~* '135'

UNION
SELECT u.unique_id, s.sender, s.message, s.msisdn_receiver, s.country_code, s.id, s.sim, s.status
     , u.id AS "uaId", s.id AS "smsId"
FROM   sms s
JOIN   user_apps u ON u.id = s.user_app_id  -- INNER JOIN !
WHERE  s.type = 'sms'
AND    u.unique_id ~* '135'
   
ORDER  BY "smsId" DESC
LIMIT  51
OFFSET 0;

fiddle
Now it should be fast.
Related:

PostgreSQL full text search on many columns


Thank you) I've added a link to dbfiddle.uk in the question. There is a ddl and test data. And in the query I added from which table the fields were selected

Any that may be in these fields. Most often, people use the last 2-4 characters to search.
For example
d1f1; 1c2c; -> must find a match with user_apps.unique_id   6242;8809; -> must find a match with sms.msisdn_receiver   9876;9877; -> must find a match with sms.id   NP;  must find a match with sms.country_code

Thank you very much. I will do all these steps on my server and give feedback

I tested, how can I share the results (explain) in the comments?

@AlexBlack: One way is to upload to https://explain.depesz.com/ and post the link.

Thank you
link - quickly(5 ms)
link - slowly(9 second), but good
link - very slowly(207 seconds). Probably trigrams are not indexed by two characters

The 2nd example returns rows=302,633 before sort & limit. That's not going to be very fast, not matter what. But it can still be substantially faster. Multiple additional options to improve, starting with memory allocation ...

3rd example: no extractable trigrams in the regexp pattern, the query plan degenerates into a full-index scan or seq scan (your case), the index isn't helpful. The query retrieves rows=1979716 before sort & limit, so it had a losing start in any case. (Maybe demand at least 3 characters?) Why do I see Sort Key: u.unique_id, s.sender, s.message, s.msisdn_receiver, s.country_code, s.id, s.sim, s.status, u.id, s.id? My query had just ORDER  BY "smsId" Either way, multiple possible improvements. But this is just a SO question, I have spend enough unpaid hours already. Good luck!

I didn't add anything new to the query to sort. I can pay you to help me. Where can we discuss of price?

@AlexBlack You can find my email in the list of Postgres contributors Contact me ...

Can we discuss the cost of optimizing this query? I will make payment immediately before optimization

Yes, exactly my line of work. Let's talk off list. I'll be home in two hours ...

It is inconvenient to discuss price and so on in the comments. Can we discuss this via messenger or email?
List:

Speed up the selection when the search is 3-4 characters long.
Create a separate index for searching by country (I think this is a separate request, because the country always has two characters and trigrams are not suitable)
It is necessary to optimize the count query for counting by status


@AlexBlack I didn't get any messages. Is this resolved?

Hello, sorry for taking a long time to respond. The issue has not been fully resolved. I'm currently waiting for a response from the customer
