# Pattern-matching for JSON values

Tags: postgresql, database-design, exists, jsonpath, postgresql-performance

Running a local docker instance of Postgres 12.5 (with 4MB `work_mem`). I'm implementing [this pattern](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/108447/3684) to search arbitrary fields in json. Goal is to search and return the JSON column `profile` quickly.

I tried an `EXISTS` subquery on a materialized view:

```sql
CREATE TABLE end_user (
    id varchar NOT NULL,
    environment_id varchar NOT NULL,
    profile jsonb NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb,
    CONSTRAINT end_user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (environment_id, id)
);

CREATE INDEX end_user_environment_id_idx ON private.end_user USING btree (environment_id);
CREATE INDEX end_user_id_idx ON private.end_user USING btree (id);
CREATE INDEX end_user_profile_idx ON private.end_user USING gin (profile);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW user_profiles AS
SELECT u.environment_id, u.id, j.key, j.value 
FROM  end_user u, jsonb_each_text(u.profile) j(key, value);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX on user_profiles (environment_id, id, key); 
CREATE INDEX user_profile_trgm_idx ON user_profiles using gin (value gin_trgm_ops);
```

I have this query which is [indexed correctly](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/108598/114293) so that it executes in a few milliseconds over a million rows. ✅

```sql
select * from user_profiles 
where value ilike '%auckland%' and key = 'timezone' and environment_id = 'test';
```

Exec time 42ms

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on user_profiles  (cost=28935.65..62591.44 rows=9659 width=65)                  
  Recheck Cond: ((value ~~* '%auckland%'::text) AND (key = 'timezone'::text))                    
  Filter: ((environment_id)::text = 'test'::text)                                              
  ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=28935.65..28935.65 rows=9659 width=0)                                     
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on user_profile_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..2923.95 rows=320526 width=0) 
              Index Cond: (value ~~* '%auckland%'::text)                                         
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on user_profiles_key_idx  (cost=0.00..26006.62 rows=994408 width=0)
              Index Cond: (key = 'timezone'::text)
```

However if I use it with an `exists` query in order to build up conditions like so:

```sql
select * users u
where 
   environment_id = 'test'
and exists (
    select 1 from user_profiles p
    where 
       value ilike '%auckland%' 
       and key = 'timezone'
       and p.id = u.id
       and environment_id = 'test'   
)
```

It performs very slowly.

Exec time 17.44 **Seconds**

```
Nested Loop  (cost=62616.01..124606.45 rows=9658 width=1459) (actual time=19206.818..28444.491 rows=332572 loops=1)                                            
  Buffers: shared hit=952734 read=624101                                                                                                                       
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=62615.59..62707.52 rows=9193 width=15) (actual time=19205.238..19292.998 rows=332572 loops=1)                                       
        Group Key: (p.id)::text                                                                                                                                
        Buffers: shared hit=373 read=246174                                                                                                                    
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on user_profiles p  (cost=28935.65..62591.44 rows=9659 width=15) (actual time=278.211..18942.629 rows=332572 loops=1)             
              Recheck Cond: ((value ~~* '%auckland%'::text) AND (key = 'timezone'::text))                                                                      
              Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 17781109                                                                                                          
              Filter: ((environment_id)::text = 'test'::text)                                                                                                
              Heap Blocks: exact=43928 lossy=197955                                                                                                            
              Buffers: shared hit=373 read=246174                                                                                                              
              ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=28935.65..28935.65 rows=9659 width=0) (actual time=272.626..272.629 rows=0 loops=1)                                         
                    Buffers: shared hit=373 read=4291                                                                                                          
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on user_profile_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..2923.95 rows=320526 width=0) (actual time=177.577..177.577 rows=332572 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (value ~~* '%auckland%'::text)                                                                                           
                          Buffers: shared hit=373 read=455                                                                                                     
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on user_profiles_key_idx  (cost=0.00..26006.62 rows=994408 width=0) (actual time=92.586..92.589 rows=1000000 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (key = 'timezone'::text)                                                                                                 
                          Buffers: shared read=3836                                                                                                            
  ->  Index Scan using end_user_id_idx on end_user u  (cost=0.42..6.79 rows=1 width=1459) (actual time=0.027..0.027 rows=1 loops=332572)                       
        Index Cond: ((id)::text = (p.id)::text)                                                                                                                
        Filter: ((environment_id)::text = 'test'::text)                                                                                                      
        Buffers: shared hit=952361 read=377927                                                                                                                 
Planning Time: 19.002 ms                                                                                                                                       
Execution Time: 28497.570 ms
```

This is a shame as the `exists` would be handy if it was fast as I would be able to add more conditions dynamically in my application code with extra conditions represented as additional `exists` clauses.

BTW a lateral join does speed this up, but I don't understand how I have such a big difference:

```sql
select * from users u,
lateral (
    select id from user_profiles p
    where 
        value ilike '%auckland%' 
        and key = 'timezone' 
        and environment_id = u.environment_id 
        and p.id = u.id
   ) ss
where u.environment_id = 'test';
```

Exec time 304ms

```
Gather  (cost=29936.07..91577.38 rows=9658 width=1474) (actual time=1100.824..15430.620 rows=332572 loops=1)                                                     
  Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                             
  Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                                            
  Buffers: shared hit=1140551 read=436286                                                                                                                        
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=28936.07..89611.58 rows=4024 width=1474) (actual time=602.490..14805.285 rows=110857 loops=3)                                           
        Buffers: shared hit=1140551 read=436286                                                                                                                  
        ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on user_profiles p  (cost=28935.65..62492.84 rows=4025 width=22) (actual time=602.078..12247.891 rows=110857 loops=3)      
              Recheck Cond: ((value ~~* '%auckland%'::text) AND (key = 'timezone'::text))                                                                        
              Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 5927036                                                                                                             
              Filter: ((environment_id)::text = 'test'::text)                                                                                                  
              Heap Blocks: exact=14659 lossy=65588                                                                                                               
              Buffers: shared hit=373 read=246174                                                                                                                
              ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=28935.65..28935.65 rows=9659 width=0) (actual time=1087.258..1087.259 rows=0 loops=1)                                         
                    Buffers: shared hit=373 read=4291                                                                                                            
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on user_profile_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..2923.95 rows=320526 width=0) (actual time=853.075..853.076 rows=332572 loops=1)  
                          Index Cond: (value ~~* '%auckland%'::text)                                                                                             
                          Buffers: shared hit=373 read=455                                                                                                       
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on user_profiles_key_idx  (cost=0.00..26006.62 rows=994408 width=0) (actual time=231.295..231.295 rows=1000000 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (key = 'timezone'::text)                                                                                                   
                          Buffers: shared read=3836                                                                                                              
        ->  Index Scan using end_user_id_idx on end_user u  (cost=0.42..6.74 rows=1 width=1459) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=1 loops=332572)                   
              Index Cond: ((id)::text = (p.id)::text)                                                                                                            
              Filter: ((environment_id)::text = 'test'::text)                                                                                                  
              Buffers: shared hit=1140178 read=190112                                                                                                            
Planning Time: 16.877 ms                                                                                                                                         
Execution Time: 15461.571 ms
```

Keen to hear any thoughts on why the `exists` subquery is so slow, and any other options I could look at here.

Distinct counts as requested by Erwin, note this is dummy data to test load but its reasonably close to production ratios

```
select count(distinct environment_id)  => 4 
     , count(distinct key)             => 33
     , count(distinct value)           => 15M  
from private.user_profiles;
```

---

Update after increasing working memory to 16MB as suggested by Erwin:

`ALTER SYSTEM SET work_mem to '16MB';`
`SELECT pg_reload_conf();`

Things are looking better with a 500ms execution time for the exists query. Which now explains like.

```
Gather  (cost=3926.79..400754.43 rows=9658 width=1459) (actual time=312.213..9396.610 rows=332572 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=1141083 read=431918
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2926.79..398788.63 rows=4024 width=1459) (actual time=155.271..8987.721 rows=110857 loops=3)
        Buffers: shared hit=1141083 read=431918
        ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on user_profiles p  (cost=2926.36..371669.88 rows=4025 width=15) (actual time=150.989..2962.870 rows=110857 loops=
              Recheck Cond: (value ~~* '%auckland%'::text)
              Filter: (((environment_id)::text = 'test'::text) AND (key = 'timezone'::text))
              Heap Blocks: exact=82556
              Buffers: shared hit=981 read=241730
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on user_profile_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..2923.95 rows=320526 width=0) (actual time=243.604..243.605 rows=332572 loops=1
                    Index Cond: (value ~~* '%auckland%'::text)
                    Buffers: shared hit=828
        ->  Index Scan using end_user_id_idx on end_user u  (cost=0.42..6.74 rows=1 width=1459) (actual time=0.054..0.054 rows=1 loops=332572)
              Index Cond: ((id)::text = (p.id)::text)
              Filter: ((environment_id)::text = 'test'::text)
              Buffers: shared hit=1140102 read=190188
Planning Time: 9.932 ms
Execution Time: 9427.067 ms
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### SQL/JSON in Postgres 12 or later

[My answer you have been working off](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/108598/3684) is dated. The current Postgres version was 9.4 in July 2015.

In Postgres 12 the whole design can be **radically simpler** with regular expressions in an SQL/JSON path expression. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#JSONPATH-REGULAR-EXPRESSIONS)

> SQL/JSON path expressions allow matching text to a regular expression with the `like_regex` filter.

With index-support, too. Scrap the materialized view. All we need is your original table and an index like:

```
CREATE INDEX end_user_path_ops_idx ON end_user USING GIN (profile jsonb_path_ops);
```

This query is equivalent to your original and can use the index:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   end_user u
WHERE  environment_id = 'test'
AND    profile @? '$.timezone ? (@ like_regex "auck" flag "i")';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=69d4c3bda233767a004ac884b17ba394)*

The one drawback is that the SQL/JSON path language needs getting used to.
Further reading:

- [Find rows containing a key in a JSONB array of records](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/196635/3684)
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH

#### Server configuration

A more basic problem becomes obvious in this line of the `EXPLAIN` output:

> Heap Blocks: exact=14659 lossy=65588

`lossy` indicates that you don't have enough **[`work_mem`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html)**. Your setting is obviously very low. (The default setting of 4 MB is way to low for a database involving tables with millions of rows.) See:

- [“Recheck Cond:” line in query plans with a bitmap index scan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/106267/3684)
- [PostgreSQL GIN index slower than GIST for pg_trgm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008382/postgresql-gin-index-slower-than-gist-for-pg-trgm/44853236#44853236)

Chances are, you need to do more in the department of server configuration. And you seem to be limited on RAM in general. I see high "read" counts, which indicates cold cache and/or a lack or mis-configuration of cache memory.

This [Postgres Wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server) can help you get started.

Comment: @Tim: *No* index on `(profile)` is applicable for the expression `eu.profile->>'timezone' ilike '%auckland%'`. A trigram expression index would: `CREATE INDEX ON end_user USING GIN ((eu.profile->>'timezone') gin_trgm_ops)`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489851/939860, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452528/939860. Faster for that particular expression. But the suggested approach with JSON path language and a `jsonb_path_ops` GIN index covers the complete JSON column, not just a single key.

Comment: I've seen two ways to do this:

`jsonb_path_exists(profile, '$.** ? (@ like_regex "auck" flag "i")')`

and

`profile @? '$.** ? (@ like_regex "auck" flag "i")'`. Do you know if both will get the same results?