# How to check whether a given value exists against a given key inside a JSON ARRAY?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a JSON type column. The JSON inside looks like this:

```
{
"user_info":
   [
     {"name":"Team member 1","email":"abc@xyz.com","employee_id":"1"},
     {"name":"Team member 2","email":"def@xyz.com","employee_id":"2"}
   ]
}
```

How do I check whether the email "abc@xyz.com" exists within this JSON?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JSON path expression:

```
select *
from the_table
where the_column @@ '$.user_info[*].email == "abc@xyz.com"';
```

This assumes that `the_column` is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's not, you need to cast it: `the_column::jsonb`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming data type [**`jsonb`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html).

You can use plain containment with the [**`@>`** operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) in any version that supports `jsonb` (Postgres 9.4+):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  js @> '{"user_info":[{"email":"abc@xyz.com"}]}';
```

See:

- [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type/22737710#22737710)

Or an SQL/JSON path expression with the [**`@?`** operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) in Postgres 12 or later:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  js @? '$.user_info[*].email ? (@ == "abc@xyz.com")';
```

See:

- [Postgres jsonb query for dynamic values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69727991/postgres-jsonb-query-for-dynamic-values/69731065#69731065)
- [Pattern-matching for JSON values: slow EXISTS subquery on materialized view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68192458/pattern-matching-for-json-values-slow-exists-subquery-on-materialized-view/68199288#68199288)

Either query can use an **index** on the JSON column, equally efficient. The [operator class `jsonb_path_ops`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html) is smaller and faster than the default `jsonb_ops` but supports a smaller set of operators:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_js_path_ops_idx ON tbl USING gin (js jsonb_path_ops);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9e9c1f1866c04b7a33a289b9c8d48583)*